# ssh_exchange_identification

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

My windows 7 system with cygwin is behind a corporate firewall, I installed corkscrew and my config file reads

```
User git
    HostName ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    ProxyCommand /d/cygwin/bin/corkscrew http://x.x.x.x 80 %h %p /c/Users/ad cd/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

But when I do `git clone ssh://git@github.com:443/rails/rails.git`,
I get the error

```
Cloning into rails...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your corkscrew config.

The first problem (and probably the real problem) is that the first argument to corkscrew should be a hostname, not a URI.  So drop the http:// prefix.  The second argument lets corkscrew know that the proxy is on port 80.

Another problem is that corkscrew uses a username:password authfile for authorizing to the proxy, not an RSA key.  Your last argument is an RSA private key, not an authfile.

Other than that, it is most likely that your RSA public key is not registered with github.

Answer (score 0):

Git just uses SSH as the transport / security so try ssh'ing straight into dev box using ssh -v to see if your keys are properly being passed and accepted.

Comment: this is what i get                                                                 $ ssh -v github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p ...
debug1: Reading configuration data ..
Applying options for github.com
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /d/cygw... 80 github.com 443
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 500debug1: identity file /c/Users/ab bc/
.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/ab bc/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/ab bc/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
Couldn't establish connection to proxy: Cannot assign requested address
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed .

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy